# HTML snapshots using the selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to capture all the visible content of a page as text. Let's say [that](https://dukescript.com/best/practices/2015/11/23/dynamic-templates.html) one for example.

If I store the page source then I won't be capturing the comments section because it's loaded using javascript.

Is there a way to take HTML snapshots with selenium webdriver?
(Preferably expressed using the python wrapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not the HTML of the page is generated using JavaScript, you will still be able to capture it using `driver.page_source`.

I imagine the reason you haven't been able to capture the source of the comments section in your example is because it's contained in an iframe - In order to capture the html source for content within a frame/iframe you'll need to first switch focus to that particular frame followed by calling `driver.page_source`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will take a screenshot of the entire page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://dukescript.com/best/practices/2015/11/23/dynamic-templates.html')
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

however, if you just want a screenshot of a specific element, you could use this:

```
def get_element_screenshot(element: WebElement) -> bytes:
    driver = element._parent
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()  # focus
    src_base64 = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    scr_png = b64decode(src_base64)
    scr_img = Image(blob=scr_png)

    x = element.location["x"]
    y = element.location["y"]
    w = element.size["width"]
    h = element.size["height"]
    scr_img.crop(
        left=math.floor(x),
        top=math.floor(y),
        width=math.ceil(w),
        height=math.ceil(h))
    return scr_img.make_blob()
```

Where the WebElement is the Element you're chasing. of course, this method requires you to import `from base64 import b64decode` and `from wand.image import Image` to handle the cropping.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear, but I need to capture the HTML, not an image

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee - Dictionary definition of snapshot is "an informal photograph taken quickly, typically with a small handheld camera."  , Please modify your question to reflect that you need to capture HTML and not an image.

Comment: @Anil_M "dictionary" definition also describes it as a technical shot in soccer. So let's not stick with the dictionary definitions because they may not capture the use of the term in another context. HTML snapshot is a quite accurate term that is being used for that I am asking, I didn't event it. Have a look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-snapshots) for example